# What is this effect called?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create an effect for an iPhone app using Xcode but not sure what it's called.

I'll describe it as best as I can:

- The goal is to slide a ball across the screen to hit a target
- User should not be able to drag it all the way as that will be too easy
- The ball should only start travelling once user releases touch
- The faster the user "slides" the object, the faster it should travel

Is this an existing effect that I can use in Xcode?

Thanks.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is a Slingshot effect.

Comment: You might look into SpriteKit, as what you are describing is a scenario best described by physics simulations (acceleration, velocity, etc). SpriteKit can implement a lot of this for you. Otherwise, I don't think there really is a specific name for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q:

> Is this an existing effect that I can use in Xcode?

A:No

However one approach would be to create a **CGVector** from a "*flick*" gesture. Then apply the vector as an impulse force on the object you're "*flicking*". The following is for use with **SpriteKit** however the principle for obtaining a vector from a "*flick*" gesture could be adopted for other frameworks.

```
#define FLICK_SCALAR 0.5 // tweak this to alter sensitivity
```

We'll need a helper struct -

```
typedef struct TouchData {
CGPoint point;
NSTimeInterval time;
} TouchData;
```

And a property -

```
@property TouchData touchOriginData;

// Touch Handling
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // store the start data
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        _touchOriginData.point = [touch locationInNode:self];
        _touchOriginData.time = [touch timestamp];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // store the end data
    TouchData touchEndData;
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        touchEndData.point = [touch locationInNode:self];
        touchEndData.time = touch.timestamp;
    }
    // calculate the impulse vector from TouchData structs
    NSTimeInterval timeTaken = touchEndData.time - _touchOriginData.time;
    CGFloat vector_x = (touchEndData.point.x - _touchOriginData.point.x) / timeTaken * FLICK_SCALAR;
    CGFloat vector_y = (touchEndData.point.y - _touchOriginData.point.y) / timeTaken * FLICK_SCALAR;
    CGVector impulseVector = CGVectorMake(vector_x, vector_y);
    // fire projectile node
    [self someMethodThatFiresWithVector:impulseVector];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say shuffleboard-like physics.  Look at cocos2d for the physics and sprite handling.  Looks like somebody has a version working http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/an-interesting-and-free-game-hishuffle/.

Answer (score 0):

It is called Slingshot effect, and you can implement it by using a Game Developing Framework such as [Cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) or [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Cocos2D Tutorial [Link](http://maniacdev.com/2012/07/tutorial-build-an-angry-birds-style-game-quickly-wcocos2d-levelhelper-and-spritehelper)

SpriteKit Tutorial [Link](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=spritekit%20angry%20birds%20tutorial&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0H1yn8UbUSs&ei=3SNTU_iJHIqF8gGXx4CoAQ&usg=AFQjCNFpnvMT8D6Sx1zLdy1WRk7dmD2vsw&sig2=Dmqadko23VGv3u4eS0dqBg&bvm=bv.65058239,d.b2U)

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't a sling shot involve pulling an object back and releasing it before it starts travelling? In my case, I'm looking to simply push the ball in a direction and it should only start travelling when touch is released. (drag should not result in any movement)

I'll have a look at SpriteKit anyway, thanks!

Comment: If I understand your desired outcome, the slingshot effect is the same.  The only difference would be instead of the dragging in the negative direction, you'd be dragging in the positive.  A little tweaking of the physics would be required.. mostly changing '-' to '+'. I think.

Comment: That's accurate @Karah .